# Pelican: "You need to specify a path containing the content"

Tags: python, macos, pelican

I've been following the [quick start guide](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/quickstart.html#installation) to some extent, but I have run into problems. As I saw it was suggested by others, I installed Python via Homebrew (I'm on OS X) and subsequently also pip. I also used virtualenvs.

So right now I have a folder virtualenvs with a subfolder pelican containing my project (with bin, site, include, lib and output folders). In the site folder (and some subfolders) the content folder resides, which currently contains the file keyboard-review.md.

The problem occurs when trying to run `pelican content` as I then get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/bin/pelican", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/__init__.py", line 386, in main
    pelican, settings = get_instance(args)
  File "/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/__init__.py", line 372, in get_instance
    settings = read_settings(config_file, override=get_config(args))
  File "/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/settings.py", line 169, in read_settings
    parsed_settings = configure_settings(local_settings)
  File "/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/settings.py", line 203, in configure_settings
    raise Exception('You need to specify a path containing the content'
Exception: You need to specify a path containing the content (see pelican --help for more information)
```

I've tried searching for how to do this, but I've come up short. Feels like it should be simple using `pelican path` but I haven't gotten it to work yet. Any help for a newbie out there?

Comment: have you tried using `pelican --help` for more information yet?

Comment: Have you run `pelican-quickstart`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, but it just says basically that I need to specify a path using `pelican path`. I tried doing so `pelican path ~/virtualenvs/pelican/site/content/`but it doesn't seem to work (says `unrecognized arguments`). Admittedly, I'm new to Python (edit: and working in the terminal in general) so maybe I'm just writing it incorrectly. Is that how I should write the command?

Comment: @Natecat Yes that's what I did. So there is a config file in which it also says `PATH = 'config'`, but maybe that is unrelated anyway to my problem?

Comment: You could go into the python file and see what it isn't finding

Comment: @Natecat and which file would that be?

Comment: It says in the stack trace: `"/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/settings.py", line 203, in configure_settings`

Comment: It seems as if `pelican ~/virtualenvs/pelican/site/content/` does the trick. Maybe `pelican content` takes a guess where the content is that but that guess may not be very good, I suppose.

Comment: Today I have come across the same error, but it was because with the latest Pelican version I had forgotten to add the - to listen. I had typed '''pelican listen''' rather than ''pelican --listen''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you try to run pelican with something like:

```
pelican ~/virtualenvs/pelican/site/content/
```

although specifying a file like this when using `python` from the terminal will work, a python program cannot use the `~/` notation when opening files so pelican has simply informed you that that is an invalid path to a file.

To fix you simply need to specify the absolute path:

```
pelican /Users/myuser/virtualenvs/pelican/site/content/
```